# Plasmolysis vs Flaccidity in cells

Tags: molecular-biology, botany, plant-physiology

When is a cell said to be flaccid and when is it called plasmolysed? 
So far I found that there is a specific relation to osmosis.

Comment: Is it a homework question? Please use the homework tag and show you effort at answering the question.

Comment: Its not a homework question. ....my doubt !!

Comment: Everything isnt homework. .... tge stack community should understand this !@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Flaccidity in plant cells**

> The failure to display turgidity especially as seen with plant cells. 
>   The suspension of cells from plants in isotonic solutions results in the state termed flaccidity. On a cellular level it represents a lack of pressure of the plasma membrane against the plant cell wall. A more extreme state, termed plasmolysis, is seen given suspension of cells in a hypertonic solution, i.e., as occurs with bacteria suspended in solutions containing high salt or sugar concentrations.

A flaccid cell is one which is in an isotonic solution, this means that the solution and the cell have an equal water conc.. Although there are always water molecules flowing into and out of the cell, they balance each other out. So a cell is referred to as flaccid when it is between being turgid and plasmolysed.

---

**Plasmolysis in plant cells**

> If a plant cell is placed in a hypertonic solution, the plant cell loses water and hence turgor pressure by plasmolysis: pressure decreases to the point where the protoplasm of the cell peels away from the cell wall, leaving gaps between the cell wall and the membrane and making the plant cell flaccid.

Sources:

- http://www.biologyaspoetry.com/terms/flaccidity_cell_biology.html
- http://study.com/academy/lesson/what-are-plasmolysis-deplasmolysis.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasmolysis

Comment: If only some water is removed from the plant cell... then is it flaccid or plasmolysed

Comment: Are you sure because my teacher said flaccid.  Flaccid is when little watr is removed and plasmolysed is when full water is removed

Comment: Even the definition of flaccid agrees

Comment: @Abcd a flaccid cell is one which is in an isotonic solution, this means that the solution and the cell have an equal water conc.. Although there are always water molecules flowing into and out of the cell, they balance each other out. 
So a cell is called flaccid when it's between being turgid and plasmolysed.

Comment: Ohk ... i agree to you but this book of mine says  : FLACCIDITY IS THE CONDITION IN WHICH THRE CELL CONTENT IS SHRUNKEN AND THE CELL IS NO MORE TIGHT

Comment: I m a tenth grade student using icse concise biology